# List of factory apps that come with the iPhone5c

Tags: iphone

What's the list of factory apps that come with the iPhone 5c my neice was playing with it and I realized it's missing a few but idk what ones because I never use most of them.

Answer (score 1):

- Messages
- Calendar
- Photos
- Camera
- Weather
- Clock
- Maps
- Videos
- Notes
- Reminders
- Stocks
- Game Center
- Newsstand
- iTunes Store
- App Store
- Passbook
- Compass
- Settings
- Phone
- Mail
- Safari
- Music
- Contacts
- Calculator
- FaceTime